# Add openssl/aes.h in Qt project

Tags: qt, ssl, aes, static-libraries

I have a custom library I've called `libdblib.a` that I'm using on several projects, and this time I would like to use it in a Qt Project.

So I've added this library as an external library through Qt Creator, so far so good.

Thing is, my library needs `openSSl` support (especially `aes` functions), and I don't understand how to add it in the project.

I've already checked this website : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html   but it seems to concern Android stuff, so I don't feel it will help

Obviously, I have the necessary ssl libraries on my computer, I'm just trying to understand how to add it in my Qt Project.

Sorry if it's an "easy question", but I'm still figuring out Qt mechanics.

I'm here if you have more questions, so far my `.pro` looks like this :

```
QT       += core gui network printsupport \
            sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

#qtHaveModule(printsupport): QT += printsupport

TARGET = myTarget
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += warn_off

SOURCES += \
/* list of my sources */

HEADERS  += \
/* list of my headers */


/* I'm guessing I have to add something here to make ssl work... */
LIBS += -lsqlite3 \
-L/usr/local/lib \
-lxml2

CONFIG += c++11

/* the following has been added by Qt creator when I imported my external lib */

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Utils/release/ -ldblib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Utils/debug/ -ldblib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Utils/ -ldblib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Utils
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Utils

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Utils/release/libdblib.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Utils/debug/libdblib.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Utils/release/dblib.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Utils/debug/dblib.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Utils/libdblib.a
```

Comment: Are your PATH environment variable has path to openssl library?

Comment: If you're already using CMake for your library, then use it for the Qt project too. (ignore this comment if you don't use CMake)